# Application starts before building and after closing application building start in my c# project on visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I click on start without debugging, my form application starts first; then when I close my form application, the building starts. After finishing building, the application again starts as normal.

Note that my other projects are okay... So I think I have some fault in my current project. But I don't find any error in my project. So what can I do now?

See my screenshots to help understand the problem.

First screenshot: When I click start without debugging, it starts my form application and the build gets stuck until I close the form.
[image: screenshot 1]

Second screenshot: After close the at first started from... see the build now succeeds and again I can start the application as normal.

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: how many forms do you have associated with your application..? perhaps you need to right click in the project solution and select a default startup project or form..

Comment: Check the pre-build events, may be you are launching the executable.

Comment: thanks a lot... the problem was because of my pre-build events command line ... :)